# What is the correct interface for NavLink isActive?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

I created a **"dumb" component** with `NavLink` and I'm creating the `interface` for his `props`, however when inserting `isActive` in my `interface` to pass the `props` he complains.

I would like to know what is the correct `interface` to add to `isActive`, remembering that this **component is "dumb"** and **will be reused**, so that its parents will pass a `function` into `isActive`.

**NAVLINK COMPONENT INTERFACE:**

```
interface ITextLinkProps {
    to: string;
    exact: boolean;
    children: React.ReactChild | React.ReactChild[];
    style?: CSSProperties;
    activeStyle?: React.CSSProperties;
    'aria-current': boolean | 'false' | 'true' | 'page' | 'step' | 'location' | 'date' | 'time';
    isActive?: (match: any, location: any) => {};
    onMouseOver?: MouseEventHandler<HTMLAnchorElement>;
    onMouseLeave?: MouseEventHandler<HTMLAnchorElement>;
}
```

**ERROR:**

```
Type '{ children: ReactChild | ReactChild[]; to: string; exact: boolean; style?: CSSProperties | undefined; activeStyle?: CSSProperties | undefined; 'aria-current': boolean | ... 6 more ... | "date"; isActive?: ((match: any, location: any) => {}) | undefined; onMouseOver?: MouseEventHandler<...> | undefined; onMouseLeave?...' is not assignable to type 'NavLinkProps<unknown>'.
  Types of property 'isActive' are incompatible.
    Type '((match: any, location: any) => {}) | undefined' is not assignable to type '(<Params extends { [K in keyof Params]?: string | undefined; }>(match: match<Params> | null, location: Location<unknown>) => boolean) | undefined'.
      Type '(match: any, location: any) => {}' is not assignable to type '<Params extends { [K in keyof Params]?: string | undefined; }>(match: match<Params> | null, location: Location<unknown>) => boolean'.
        Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.  TS2322
```

I already tried to add the own `interface` of this property which is:

```
isActive?<Params extends { [K in keyof Params]?: string }>(match: match<Params> | null, location: H.Location<S>): boolean;
```

But `typescript` starts to accuse import errors:

```
match' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof match'?  TS2749

     9 |    'aria-current': boolean | 'false' | 'true' | 'page' | 'step' | 'location' | 'date' | 'time';
    10 |    isActive?<Params extends { [K in keyof Params]?: string }>(
  > 11 |        match: match<Params> | null,
       |               ^
    12 |        location: H.Location<S>
    13 |    ): boolean;
    14 |    onMouseOver?: MouseEventHandler<HTMLAnchorElement>;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper type is NavLinkProps.

```
import { NavLink, NavLinkProps } from 'react-router-dom';

const CustomNavLink = (props: NavLinkProps) => <NavLink {...props} />
```

If you want to extend the default interface you can do something like

```
import { NavLink, NavLinkProps } from 'react-router-dom';

interface ITextLinkProps extends NavLinkProps {
  customProp: string;
}

const CustomNavLink = (props: ITextLinkProps) => <NavLink {...props} />
```

Ensure your isActive prop returns a boolean:

```
isActive={() => {
  return true;
}}
```

Comment: Type '() => void' is not assignable to type '<Params extends { [K in keyof Params]?: string | undefined; }>(match: match<Params> | null, location: Location<unknown>) => boolean'.
  Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.

Comment: isActive={() => setIsActived(true)}

Comment: I updated the post, you are not returning anything so the function is void you must return a boolean.

Comment: Worked, thank you! Is it a problem to use userState within isActive? He complains about the following: "the bad setState () call inside` Router.Consumer`, follow the stack trace as described "

Comment: I would not set state inside of isActive as it is meant only to be used to toggle a CSS class.  I'd use react-router-dom's useLocation hook and check the pathname against a path and set the state in that function.  Here is a decent example  https://css-tricks.com/the-hooks-of-react-router/#uselocation

Comment: interface ITextLinkProps extends Partial<NavLinkProps> {
  label: string
  path: string
  icon: string
  tooltip: boolean
}

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your return type is incorrect. You want `(match: any, location: any) => boolean`.
You can see it in the last line of the error:

```
        Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.  TS2322
```

You might also try using the props directly: `NavLinkProps<unknown>["isActive"]`.